# TV studio set reverbation treatment?

Tags: recording, reverb, acoustics, room-treatment

Hi all, I currently work on a TV project (sitcom), which is being shooted in big TV studio. They built some family house rooms there. But basically the studio is very big - 20m width, 60m length, 15m height and rooms don't have any ceiling (of course - due to lighting) and they don't have one or two walls either. 
As you can imagine there is a lot of reverbation on the dialog, which is more than inadequate to what you see on TV later. 
Do you have some skills with treating this reverb in similar location?
I was thinking of placing some rock wool material there, but cannot imagine how much and where to put them for such a big space.
Thanks for any ideas ;-)
*Sorry for my english :-O*

Answer (score 1):

There exist acoustic sails you can install/ hang from the ceiling. so light comes through.

You can use some molton fabric to make some kind of walls.
Just put them on special sliders etc. like you put your curtains on. So you can move the fabric to every
shooting position/ direction.

If not possible to install just use tripods/ stands with crokos from the lighting department to "narrow" the room.

Use carpets or molton as carpets.

another idea ist to build things like this:
http://realtraps.com/p_gobo.htm
But for the insulation don´t buy rockwool- 
it´s to itching when a lot of air movement occurs.
Use basotect instead. 
Or hemp wool :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use lapels? Or in post, use Waves RVox plugin (sometimes it's too clean and missing a human quality), but be sure to keep all movements in separate tracks. Können wir auf Deutsch sprechen?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find out some acoustical solution for entire space. I use lapels of course, but it's not so good as a boom mike. And one more problem - to clean lapels tracks and match them with the phase of boom tracks takes time which I don't have, is a very fast production model - sitcom. PS: I don't speak German, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

How about this plugin http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yitJOeFkscc&sns=em